# Why split() is returning two lists from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, list, split, network-programming

I am implementing a simple client and server in Python 3.7.2. Client will send two numbers to the server and sever will add them and send it back to the client.

Here is my implementation:-

Client:-

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 4444

a = input('Enter 1st no: ')
b = input('Enter 2nd no: ')
c = (a + ',' + b).encode()
print(c)

s.connect((host, port))
print('Sending string {} to the server'.format(c.decode()))
s.sendall(c)

data = s.recv(1024)
print(int(data))

s.close()
```

Server:-

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 4444

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)
print('Waiting for connections...')
conn, addr = s.accept()


while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    d = data.decode().split(',')
    print(d)
    print(type(d))
    data_add = int(d[0]) +int(d[1])
    conn.sendall(str(data_add).encode())

conn.close()
```

Output:-

Server:-

```
Waiting for connections...
['3', '6']
<class 'list'>
['']
<class 'list'>
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "addserver.py", line 19, in
>   
>       data_add = int(d[0]) +int(d[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Client:-

```
Enter 1st no: 3                 
Enter 2nd no: 6                 
b'3,6'                          
Sending string 3,6 to the server
9
```

For debugging purposes I have added some print statements. Now the problem here is I am sending only one byte to the server(See client's output) but the server is returning two lists from that data(a string), 1st one is expected and 2nd one is a empty list. How is this possible? That's why a `ValueError` is occurring too.
Although I got an expected output at client side but I am curious to know why `split()` returned two lists instead of just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is simple. You get empty `d`, when client closes connection.
Actually I see bad logic behind relationship of server and client.
I mean, you do that:

1.
client connects to server

2.
client and server do their things: a + b

3.
client closes connection, while server waits for data <-- problem is here!

Maybe you want to use one connection per client?
Yes, you do. It's strange, if you don't.

So... just move `conn, addr = s.accept()` into `while` block:

```
... # some server init code
#conn, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    ... # some per client code
```